# How can I get the UTC value of a date and time in a time zone in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I'd like to be able to create a Date object with a time like "Midnight in Los Angeles on Christmas 2011".

I've used [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which is great, and [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), which is even better, but neither the default Date class nor the moment constructors take a timezone as an argument.

I've been able to fudge it by using a formatted RFC2822 string, like so:

```
 d = new Date("12-25-2011 PST")
```

...but it requires that I know that December 25 is standard time. This gives a different answer:

```
d = new Date("12-25-2011 PDT")
```

Ideally I'd like to use geographical-style timezones like "America/Los_Angeles".

Comment: The date values are always UTC internally. You only get the timezones in formatted date output strings. So I guess you'll have to create your own class to hold a date and a timezone, and calculate manually.

Comment: @bfavaretto Yes, but I expect that since it's a common problem there's a library that does it.

Answer (score 1):

See moment-timezone [#11](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/11) and [#25](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/pull/25).

If you get the latest develop from GitHub sources, you can do this:

```
moment.tz('2011-12-25T00:00:00','America/Los_Angeles').utc().format()
```

The only reason it hasn't been released yet is because we're still deciding what to do about ambiguous or invalid input, per [#27](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/pull/27).

Comment: That's an interesting conversation! It looks like https://github.com/bigeasy/timezone does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I know how to do this. I'm using the great [timezone](http://npmjs.org/package/timezone) package from npm. Here's the rough idea:

```
var tz = require("timezone");

var dateInZone = function(dt, zone) {
    return new Date(tz(dt, zone, require("timezone/"+zone), "%FT%T%^z"));
};

console.log(dateInZone([2011, 12, 25], "America/Los_Angeles"));
```